# How to get the name of the running script without the extension

Tags: perl

I am interested in getting the name of the running script without the `.pl`
This: `my ($script) = $0 =~ /(.*)\.pl/;` seems to work. I was wondering if there is another more standard way for this

Answer (score 3):

Use `fileparse` from [File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aBasename). This is a core module so it's always available to your distribution.

```
use File::Basename;
my ( $name, $path, $suffix ) = fileparse( $0, qr{\.[^.]*$} );
print "NAME=$name\n";
print "PATH=$path\n";
print "SFFX=$suffix\n";
```

The regular expression to find the `suffix` looks for a dot, followed by anything that isn't a dot, zero or more times, anchored to the end of the string.

If the running script was`/mypath/myfile.pl` this returns:

```
NAME=myfile
PATH=/mypath/
SFFX=.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

the scriptname is in

```
print $0;
```

like you wrote..

if you want to have only the name without .pl

-i- would do this:

```
my $script = $0;
$script =~ s/\.pl//;
```

i dont think that here is any performance issue to choose this or that one ;)

[see perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 0):

the last example is if you run the program without the path. But from crontab
    /path/to/dir/script.pl

```
my $script = $0;   
$script =~ s/\.pl//;
```

will give you

```
 /path/to/dir/script
```